# Edit/finetune shapes drawn by Opencv

Tags: opencv

My requirement is to draw a rectangle on an image using program and allow the user to fine tune the length/width position with the mouse. And, get back the modified details into the program. I am using OpenCV, Linux.

Currently I am using library function to draw the basic shape on the image

polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(0,0,255), 2, LINE_AA);

I understand the shape drawn here is part of the image and not treated as a layer above the image. Harder way to achieve what I want is

- Highlight the shape by placing small filled circles at the corners and filling the shape by translucent color, upon mouse click
- track the mouse drag and move the corners accordingly to re-size the shape, if first clicked on the corner circles
- if clicked within, move the shape itself

The program has to continuously check for mouse clicks, track their movement and keep drawing shapes at new position to give user the feedback.

Is there any single function to achieve the same or any easier method?

Thank you.

Comment: Method you described seems the way to do it. What do you expect us to help you with in this question? If it's a one-liner you are looking for, there isn't any.

Comment: I don't think there's a single function to do this.
The way standard mspaint-like applications work is to keep redrawing the rectangle with newer dimensions as long as the mouse is kept pressed.

You might want to distinguish between the mouse-click event and mouse-press events for this to work seamlessly.

Comment: @slawekwin I was hoping there could be an API to achieve the above. If it isn't, I'll try myself and post the code when I'm done. Thanks for your reply